# Compare HTML files with Beyond Compare while treating them as plain text files

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

Can someone give me the hint how to configure Beyond Compare so the compared HTML files as treated as plain text files. Currently when I compare 2 HTML files the contents are shown in a tabular view, which is not very helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

By default Beyond Compare does compare HTML files as plain text, but we have an add-on file format that will tell it to pull out tables and display them in a table instead.  Use the `Tools > File Formats` command to open the configuration dialog, find the `HTML to CSV` item in the list on the left and uncheck it.  It should then compare the files in the text compare like you're expecting.  Next time you do want to compare just the tables you can use the "Compare Using" command to open the files in the Data/Table Compare viewer and then select the file format manually from the **Format** toolbar button dropdown.